# Is it possible to write a GUI desktop app in F# + mono on Mac and have it run without modification on Windows?

Tags: f#, mono

I'm interested in developing desktop apps for Windows, but it would be most convenient if I could develop these apps on my Mac OS X Air laptop, without running a virtualization environment. How far can you get developing Windows GUI Desktop apps using mono and F# on OS X?

Answer (score 1):

If you aim for WPF - not far. Sadly, you will have problems with WPF even in a virtualized Windows environment, as it uses 3D acceleration.

Sticking to the "traditional" Windows Forms works, but they are not the preferred way to create new applications nowadays.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 is a WPF app and that runs ok in VMWare Fusion on Mac OS.

Comment: As long as it runs without 3D acceleration. So you are testing your code in an environment that works much slower than the 'real deal'. I'm not saying this doesn't work, I use it myself, it's just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cross-platform UI toolkit. Monodevelop uses [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/GtkSharp), there are probably others. It'll run everywhere without modification but will look somewhat alien everywhere. That's the tradeoff you make for not having to make a different UI per platform.

Instructions for using F# from Monodevelop are detailed [here](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Resources/GetMono.aspx). Hopefully with that you should be good to go!

Comment: F# binding for Monodevelop is pretty out of date.